Tomcat JAX-RS 404 page not found
I have created a jakarta rest service project
and then when I run it, I got 404 error
there's no interface after I visit the path.
I created these two classes:
package com.mpsoft.generateur;
  import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
 import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
 import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
  @Path("/hello-world")
 public class HelloResource
 {
     @GET
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public String hello() {
         return "Hello, World!";
     } }

package com.mpsoft.generateur;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

}

And this is what I've got:

This is more details about the project:


For JakartaEE you need a JakartaEE compliant server. You are using Tomcat 9 which isn't JakartaEE compliant but JavaEE so it won't work. You need at least Tomcat 10 which is JakartaEE compliant.

https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Tomcat supports only a few of the dozens of technologies defined in Jakarta EE. Jakarta RESTful Web Services is not among them. Use a more full-featured app server that does support your desired features. Look for a server product that supports at least the Web Profile. Examples include OpenLiberty, WebSphere, Payara, Glassfish, WildFly, JBoss, etc.
